# Forcing a sqlalchemy ORM get() outside identity map

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

**Background**

The `get()` method is special in SQLAlchemy's ORM because it tries to return objects from the identity map before issuing a SQL query to the database (see the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get)).

This is great for performance, but can cause problems for distributed applications because an object may have been modified by another process, so the local process has no ability to know that the object is dirty and will keep retrieving the stale object from the identity map when `get()` is called.

---

**Question**

*How can I force `get()` to ignore the identity map and issue a call to the DB every time?*

---

**Example**

- I have a `Company` object defined in the ORM.
- I have a `price_updater()` process which updates the `stock_price` attribute of all the `Company` objects every second.
- I have a `buy_and_sell_stock()` process which buys and sells stocks occasionally.

  - Now, inside this process, I may have loaded a `microsoft = Company.query.get(123)` object.
  - A few minutes later, I may issue another call for `Company.query.get(123)`.  The stock price has changed since then, but my `buy_and_sell_stock()` process is unaware of the change because it happened in another process.
  - Thus, the `get(123)` call returns the stale version of the `Company` from the session's identity map, which is a problem.

I've done a search on SO(under the [sqlalchemy] tag) and read the SQLAlchemy docs to try to figure out how to do this, but haven't found a way.

Comment: Check out [`Session.expunge(...)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expunge) call before every `get(...)`. It might just be enough for you. However, I am not convinced this is the best practice for the UseCase.

Comment: Thanks @van would you happen to know how to check whether an instance for a given ID is in the identity map?  Otherwise expunge may end up being a very expensive operation if I need to retrieve the object before expunging it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`session.expire(my_instance)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expire) will cause the data to be re-selected on access.  However, even if you use `expire` (or `expunge`), the next data that is fetched will be based on the transaction isolation level.  See the [PostgreSQL docs on isolations levels](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) (it applies to other databases as well) and the [SQLAlchemy docs on setting isolation levels](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#session-transaction-isolation).

You can test if an instance is in the session with `in`: [`my_instance in session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#session-attributes).

You can [use `filter` instead of `get` to bypass the cache](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html?highlight=get#is-the-session-a-cache), but it still has the same isolation level restriction.

```
Company.query.filter_by(id=123).one()
```